# Deleting and inserting in a single visual block selection

Tags: insert-mode, visual-block

I'm trying to understand how the visual-block mode deals with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and if it is possible to vertically select a column of text, delete some characters, then insert new ones in a single selection.

For example, with these 3 lines of code (each proceeded with 2 spaces):

```
  a = 1;  
  b = 2;  
  c = 3;
```

With my cursor on `a` I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> selecting all the letters, then <kbd>I</kbd> to go into insert mode. At this point I can delete the two preceeding spaces with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> then start typing `var` but when I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> I get the following:

```
var a = 1;
  r b = 2;
  r c = 3;
```

I don't understand why Vim is not including the `va` on the last two lines. I ran some other tests with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key and noticed that neither of these actions are applied to other lines, however I would then expect something like:

```
var a = 1;
  var b = 2;
  var c = 3;
```

What is the multiline cursor doing that causes `va` to be overwritten/ignored? Also, I know that I can select the two columns of spaces and delete them with <kbd>d</kbd> then reselect the three lines and type `var`, but is there a way to do this only having to make the selection once?

[deletion then insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Yse.jpg)

[deletion tests](https://imgur.com/a/Le8qS)

---

I've tested this without a `vimrc`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of deleting with <kbd>d</kbd>, select `spaces` in Visual Block Mode and press <kbd>c</kbd>, then type `var`. Difference is that <kbd>c</kbd> performs two operations at once - it deletes text and stays in Insert Mode after that.

As for why Vim is not including `va` - simply it's outside of the visually selected block. I couldn't find anything about that in the `:help`, but I think Vim is not extending selection left on <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and it doesn't repeat all the keystrokes like in a macro. It just copies text inserted within seleted area and pastes it after to the remaining lines of selection.